# On VBA (excel), is it possible to clear a listbox's display values without clearing the datasource?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, listboxitem

Here is how I establish the listbox:

```
Dim iRow As Long 
iRow = [counta(Tally!A:A)]
With TallySheet
If iRow > 1 Then
        .lstdatabase.RowSource = "Tally!A2:E" & iRow
        Else
        .lstdatabase.RowSource = "Tally!A2:E2"
        
        End If
End With
```

However the issue I am facing is that the only ways I have found of resetting the listbox display involve clearing the actual data stored in the excel sheet. I haven't been able to find any information on how to simply reset the display but leave the original values. Would I need to use two worksheets for this?

What I am aiming for is being able to reset the display without deleting the information stored in the excel sheet. I have tried things like `Listbox1.Clear` and `ListBox1.RowSource = ""` I also tried `lstDatabase.RowSource = vbNullString` which I found in another post, but it clears the whole data source instead of just clearing the list box.

Comment: Did you try `.lstdatabase.Clear`?

Comment: @z32a7ul I tried '.lstdatabase.Clear' , but it says it's an "invalid or unqualified reference"

Comment: @z32a7ul I also tried 'ME.lstdatabse.clear' which doesn't give me the invalid error but instead gives me a "Run-time Error '-2147467259 Unspecified Error"

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem is: You used a Form control (as opposed to a more usable ActiveX control) ListBox.

But no problem you can access it like this (I tested this code from a Module):

```
Public Sub TestSub()
    Dim iRow As Long: iRow = [counta(Tally!A:A)]
    iRow = 0 ' to test if emptying works
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tally").Shapes("lstdatabase").ControlFormat
        If 1 < iRow Then
            .ListFillRange = "Tally!A2:E" & iRow
        Else
            .ListFillRange = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You didn't mention but I suppose that not only emptying did not work but the line to fill it up (`.lstdatabase.RowSource = "Tally!A2:E" & iRow`) was wrong, as well.

So, setting `ListFillRange` to empty will clear the ListBox, however, you should think over the logic of your code: If you count entries in `A:A`, then you cannot clear the ListBox without clearing `A:A`. But that is not because its not possible just because you refer to `A:A` here: `iRow = [counta(Tally!A:A)]`.

Also note that `"Tally!A2:E" & iRow` doesn't make much sense, only the first column is taken into consideration by Excel, so it should be `"Tally!A2:A" & iRow`.

Comment: Would it be beneficial to use a separate variable to keep track of how many rows are occupied? I tried 'With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tally").Shapes("lstdatabase").ControlFormat' but it gives me "item with specified name wasn't found" I am pretty new to Excel VBA.

Comment: Make sure, that Tally is the ActiveSheet and issue this command in the Immediate Window, then copy the results and paste them in here: `For Each S In ActiveSheet.Shapes: Debug.Print "'" & S.Name & "' " & TypeName(S) & " " & S.Type: Next`.